Connotation of "athlete's foot"
Apart from denoting the skin condition affecting the toes, which is naturally undesirable, do you all feel that "athlete's foot" has any (positive) connotations, e.g. to the effect of being indicative of or caused by an active lifestyle? Otherwise I could not imagine why a retailer would choose this name.
The German equivalent, "Fußpilz", which translates to "foot fungus", is (in my perception) something of a mild taboo and connotes its origin in unsanitary conditions, even if that is not actually true.

The common name is athlete's foot, and no of course it has no "positive connotations" It's called that because athletes contract it in locker rooms. The only retailer I know is: The Foot Locker. I fail to see how a common ailment of the foot can be "taboo" in German culture. Why not ask the guys from Bayer de Munich if they think it's taboo?

I assume the OP means that if https://www.theathletesfoot.com.au/ were "www.dieFußpilz.de"  it would be gross rather than playful.

The US store by that name contains the word "the" but it's still a bad name. https://www.theathletesfoot.com.au/about-us/history

@Lambie - I think 'jock itch' has even fewer positive connotations. I've never had it, but it doesn't sound like something to 'discuss at the dinner table' as my father would have said.

@MichaelHarvey That is much worse than athlete's foot. But neither is suitable for talking about when eating. One needn't go back to your or my father's generation.

@Lambie - not long before Christmas when my sister was six, the radio was tuned to a BBC religious broadcast. An Anglican priest solemnly spoke of 'the Virgin Mary'. 'Dad, what's a virgin?' from little sister. 'We don't talk about them at the dinner table' said Dad. I now think there might have been a hint of amusement in his voice.

Shop names will use jokes and double meanings.  "Athlete's foot" is the name for a fungal disease, but it doesn't actually mention "fungus", so it is available for the double meaning, or rather the literal meaning "a foot of an athlete"
Of course, if you say "I have athlete's foot", it just means "foot fungus" and has no positive meaning.  But if you stray from the idiom and say "I have the feet of an athlete" it could be positive or negative according to what you want to imply.
In fact the mere addition of an article  "the athlete's foot", gives this a sense that is separate from the fungus meaning, and suggests "the foot of an athlete".
